# Access form 'fields' in django View class

Tags: django, forms, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to access the 'fields' attribute in my Class based View

Here's an example of what my forms.py looks like:

```
from django import forms
from .models import ErrorEvent


class ErrorEventForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = HumanErrorEvent
        # fields =
        exclude = ['event_id', 'user_modified', 'date_modified']
        widgets = {
            'owner': forms.TextInput(),
        }
```

Then here's my views:

```
class ErrorCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = "forms/form.html"
    form_class = ErrorEventForm
    model = ErrorEvent

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        if not self.request.user.groups.filter(name='leaders').exists():
            self.form_class.fields['owner'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
        context = super(ErrorCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

The error I am getting is:

```
AttributeError: type object 'ErrorEventForm' has no attribute 'fields'
```

Due to this line:

```
self.form_class.fields['owner'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
```

Is it not possible to access the 'fields' attribute in the views? If not, is there a way to hide the 'owner' form field based on the group the user is in?

Thank you for all your help in advance!

Comment: Why hide the user, and not simply use the `request.user` when you *submit* the form?

Comment: That's what is normally done, but I want to be able to have certain people the privilege to either change who the owner is or create one in someone else's name.

Comment: then you can add a `ModelChoiceField` to your form.

Comment: How does that solve my problem?

Comment: then the form contains a drop down list of the user that can be selected to change the owner to.

Comment: I only want certain people to be given the privilege, not everyone.

Comment: of course, you should only add that field to the form in the `if` case...

Comment: @mike_gundy123 the `fields` attribute of the form is only added to the form when it is _instantiated_. The form class itself does not have it. Also `get_context_data` is not the best method to override for doing this.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat ahh gotcha, there's also a 'get_inital' method. Should I put it there? Also what you're saying I can't access the 'fields' attribute after the form object has been created?

Comment: @mike_gundy123 `ErrorEventForm.fields` won't work but with an _instance_ of the form `ErrorEventForm().fields` it will, you are trying to access it on the form class instead of on the instance.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat ohhhhhh, so ErrorEventForm() is an instance, but ErrorEventForm isn't? What is ErrorEventForm then? (sorry for noob questions)

Comment: `ErrorEventForm` is a class. And `ErrorEventForm()` will give an instance of the form, anyway check answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fields` attribute of the form is only added when the form is *instantiated* the form class itself does not have it. Also `get_context_data` is not the best method to override for doing such things, a better method would perhaps be `get_form`, so you could write something like:

```
def get_form(self, form_class=None):
    form = super().get_form(form_class=form_class)
    form.fields['owner'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
    return form
```

But we can still do better than this! Shouldn't such logic belong to the form class *itself*? Hence it would be better to simply pass the user to the form class. You can do this by overriding `get_form_kwargs` and the forms `__init__` method:

```
# Form
class ErrorEventForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = HumanErrorEvent
        # fields =
        exclude = ['event_id', 'user_modified', 'date_modified']
        widgets = {
            'owner': forms.TextInput(),
        }
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if user and not user.groups.filter(name='leaders').exists():
            del self.fields['owner']  # Remove the field itself from the form
            self.instance.owner = user  # Set the user as the owner


# View
class ErrorCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = "forms/form.html"
    form_class = ErrorEventForm
    model = ErrorEvent
    
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs
```

Comment: thank you for the help! and what's the point of these line?
super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()

Also how would i handle this on the html side?
        <div class="col-md-3">
        {{ form.owner|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
but when i remove it i obv get an error since it doesn't exist

Comment: @mike_gundy123 `super().<method_call>` simply calls the super method, I believe you were already using that like `super(ErrorCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)` (You can skip the two arguments in python3)? As for that error, I had thought you were rendering the form directly, to solve it you can enclose it in an if: `{% if form.owner %}<div class="col-md-3"> {{ form.owner|as_crispy_field }} </div>{% endif %}`

Comment: im making changes to an existing system, so i don't write that part lol. Thanks for all your help! it works!